# Python equivalent of PowerShell Get-EventLog

Tags: python, windows, powershell, event-log

In PowerShell you can run this command to list all of the different Event Log folders on a server:

```
Get-EventLog -list
```

Is there a way to do this in Python? I've seen many posts about how to get logs from a specific folder (using e.g. `win32evtlog`), but not how to retrieve a list of all the Event Log folders. I'm running Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
>>> import win32evtlog
>>> x = win32evtlog.EvtOpenChannelEnum()
>>> win32evtlog.EvtNextChannelPath(x)
u'Application'
>>> win32evtlog.EvtNextChannelPath(x)
u'HardwareEvents'
>>> win32evtlog.EvtNextChannelPath(x)
u'Internet Explorer'
>>>
```